"App" Plugin Not Implemented on iOS After Upgrading Capacitor to Version 6
Question:
I’ve recently upgraded my Capacitor project to version 6, and after updating, I encountered the following error in Xcode:
⚡️  [log] - "App" plugin is not implemented on ios
Are there any additional configurations or setup steps required for Capacitor version 6 and the @capacitor/app plugin on iOS?
Is there a need for any manual changes in the iOS project files or AppDelegate.swift?
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Additional Information:
Capacitor version: 6
Thank you!
I've tried many thing like
in VSCODE
ionic build
npx cap sync
pod update
XCode
cleaning
rebuilding
reruning

Have you doubled checked the following steps from the official upgrade guide? https://capacitorjs.com/docs/updating/6-0

Thank you for your response. I've reviewed the documentation and it appears that I followed all the instructions correctly, but I am still encountering this error.
i'm really stucked any suggestions?

edit your post to add your ionic info please. this will help a lot. run ionic info in the command prompt.

Are they custom plugins? I had the same issue and missed the fact Capacitor 6 removes automatic plugin registration on iOS.
https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/7443#issuecomment-2149692714
